# Is it possible to host OptaWeb on IIS

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I'm quite new when it comes to anything open-source.  While I was able to successfully run OptaWeb by following the user guide, is there a way to implement/host OptaWeb on IIS?  How?

Answer (score 0):

No. If I recall correctly, Microsoft IIS does not support Java 11 or higher.

The `optaweb-employee-rostering` process is an HTTP server on it's own. Same for the new employee rostering quickstart with Quarkus. You can maybe have IIS redirect to those, not sure.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the quick response.